# reading cdata with binary data in xml by java

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have an XML which is coming as response of a SOAP  web service. The XML is like following--

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><pro_code>ABCE096</pro_code>  <pdf_stream>JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iajw8L0Jhc2VGb250L1RpbWVzLVJvbWFuL1R5cGUvRm9udC9F&#13;</pdf_stream>]]>
```

By using following I have picked up PRO_CODE

```
xpath.compile("//illustrations/product_code/text()").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET))....
```

But, pdf_stream is a byteStream. How I can read that and convert to PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of your pdf is obviously encoded in `Base64`. You can decode it using `Base64.getDecoder().decode(String)` if you use Java 8.

You can find more details about the `Base64` decoder [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html).

If you don't use Java 8, you can still use [Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from `Apache Commons Codec`.

**NB:** You have a trailing HTML entity (&#13) that you will need to remove first

Comment: I am using java 6. do i need to use any library, if yes which one please?